# UIButton stretching image when selected

Tags: objective-c, ios, uibutton

I have a rectangle UIButton which I set the content mode to UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit because the image is not always the same size of the button.

```
[btnPlaylist.imageView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
```

The thing is that when I hit the button, the image stretches like it was UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill, ignoring that it already fits vertical or horizontal size.

What am I missing?

Comment: The problem is that UIButtons have multiple images for the different control states.  I don't think you have direct access to the other imageviews.

Comment: I tried adding the same image for the 3 states: UIControlStateNormal, UIControlStateSelected and UIControlStateHighlighted.

Comment: forgot to say that setting the image for the 3 control states didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try turning off `adjustsImageWhenHighlighted`? Perhaps if this property is `NO` it won't mess with your image.

> `adjustsImageWhenHighlighted`   A Boolean value that determines whether
>   the image changes when the button is highlighted.
>
> `@property(nonatomic) BOOL adjustsImageWhenHighlighted`
>   Discussion
>   If YES, the image is drawn lighter when the button is highlighted. The
>   default value is YES.
>
> Availability   Available in iOS 2.0 and later.

Comment: Nice, it works, but it give me another problem. When I set adjustsImageWhenHighlighted to NO, the button loses the dim effect showing that it was selected.

Comment: Try setting showsTouchWhenHighlighted to YES. It is no by default, but I think it does what you want.  Good luck.

Comment: Didn't work... at least, not dimming is a smaller issues than resizing the image.